# Signature capture in Web using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to capture signature from Ruby on Rails application and store it as image. Is there a suitable plugin for this in Ruby on Rails?

**Edit**

I want something like this in Ruby on Rails(I think this is in dot net):

[http://www.realsignature.com/](http://www.realsignature.com/demo/default.aspx)

http://www.realsignature.com/demo/default.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by "capture signature"? What kind of signature is it?

Comment: I think he means he needs to be able to accept a persons signature like when you sign for a UPS package and save it as an image in a rails app.

@rubyprince please edit your question to be a little more descriptive. What's your method of getting the signature in the first place?

Comment: @caley, @arnep...I have edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had great success using Thomas Bradley's [Signature Pad](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad) jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as asked, no, currently there is no gem nor plugin for this.

Comment: You could potentially look at doing something in HTML5 with canvas but that isn't rails specific.

Answer (score 0):

Rails can easily upload images, but capturing an image from a stylus somehow is beyond the scope of web applications.